# Add a character every nth character in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I can't find an expression to add a character every nth character from the right of a string, in field calculator.

As an example, I have a list of UK postcodes which I need to add a space to 3 characters from the right:

From: N165KP To: N16 5KP

Note this has to be done from the right as the first lot of characters (before the space) can vary in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
left("Postcode", length("Postcode")-3) + ' ' + right("Postcode", 3)
```

It takes all characters of `Postcode` except the last three ones, adds a space and then appends the last three characters.

Edit.: I tested this in QGIS 2.18.22

Comment: Why not just to use `left("Postcode", 3)  ||  ' '  ||  right("Postcode", 3)`?

Comment: Your proposal turns `DD115KP` into `DD1 5KP` (Note the missing 1 in the middle).

Comment: I thought the "Postcode" field is limited to six characters, but it is about n-characters. And I double checked the Note in the question, now it is clear.